# Timer to wait before each KeySend C#

Tags: c#, flash, timer, wait, shockwave

I've just started and I still can't find an answer for this.
I don't know how to make the timer wait a little before sending the next key.

As you can see this just executes them all at the same time then looping the process

```
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        axShockwaveFlash1.Select();
        SendKeys.SendWait("{UP}");
        axShockwaveFlash1.Select();
        SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}");
        axShockwaveFlash1.Select();
        SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
        axShockwaveFlash1.Select();
        SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}");
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you add a Shockwave/Flash tag? It would make it easier for people to find and identify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what language it's, but a thing like

```
Thread.Sleep();
```

may be what you're looking for.

EDIT: This function exists in C#

Comment: yeah I forgot to mention it.